# Excel Olap Tools MDX Calculated Measure - formula [child value] / [parent value]

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

Fist off, let me just apoligize if this question has been asked already.  I have searched all day trying to find an answer but haven't been able to figure things out.

I"m trying to create a calculated measure.  Please see screen shot bellow for a description. This is the best way I know how to describe the problem.

[image]

Comment: please add the `mdx` of the calculation in its current implementation

Comment: Do you have access to the Analysis Services solution to create a new measure? Or do you want to do this in OLAP PivotTable Extensions

Comment: Hi - unfortunately, I do not have access to the analysis server, so I need to setup the measure in OLAP.